# Working with C#: How do I iterate through a nested JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I am pulling in a large amount of JSON data for items. Each item has set of particular data that I am wanting to grab and place in a list.

Here is a sample of two of the over 700 items contained in the JSON data.
I need to be able to iterate through the JSON data using Newtonsoft.JSON and pull the data at "items", "values", "value" for the "fieldName": "Item ID". I need to do this for all 700 items returned in the JSON data. How do I iterate through this data and access just that particular data?

```
{
items: [    
    {
      "createDate": 1468872878834,
      "updateDate": 1498075185297,
      "deleted": 0,
      "allListsItemCount": 0,
      "assets": [
        {
          "createDate": 1469129652323,
          "updateDate": 1471625094427,
          "deleted": 0,
          "url": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg",
          "parentId": 10270308,
          "typeId": 4000014573,
          "filename": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg",
          "seqOrder": 1,
          "printActive": 1,
          "webActive": 1,
          "thumbnail": 1,
          "flag1": 1,
          "typeName": "Web Thumbnail Image",
          "typeGroupCode": "PRIM",
          "id": 4063212155,
          "transformationSource": false,
          "primaryAsset": false
        },
        {
          "createDate": 1469129652323,
          "updateDate": 1471625094427,
          "deleted": 0,
          "url": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif",
          "parentId": 10270308,
          "typeId": 4000014572,
          "filename": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif",
          "seqOrder": 2,
          "printActive": 1,
          "webActive": 0,
          "typeName": "Print Image",
          "typeGroupCode": "PRIM",
          "id": 4063212156,
          "transformationSource": false,
          "primaryAsset": false
        }
      ],
      "masterCategoryId": 4000593879,
      "listsCount": 0,
      "advTablesCount": 0,
      "id": 10270308,
      "values": [
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002078,
          "fieldName": "Amps",
          "value": "19.20/9.60"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20000921,
          "fieldKey": "Item_ID",
          "fieldName": "Item ID",
          "value": "USQ1152"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002075,
          "fieldKey": "Inv_Mast_UID",
          "fieldName": "Inv_Mast_UID",
          "value": "6736"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002081,
          "fieldName": "Bearings",
          "value": "Sealed Ball"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002141,
          "fieldKey": "Web_Description",
          "fieldName": "Web&UPC Description",
          "value": "CENTURY MOTOR                     NS"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002190,
          "fieldKey": "Web_Image",
          "fieldName": "Image Name LR",
          "value": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002191,
          "fieldName": "Image Name HR",
          "value": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002089,
          "fieldName": "Features",
          "value": "Used on many Sta-Rite - Red Jacket, Pac Fab & American pprojets and Sears jet and pool pumps,High & low service factors, 303 Stainless steel threaded shaft, 50 Degrees C ambient, Capacitor sart"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002088,
          "fieldName": "Enclosure",
          "value": "Open Drip Proof"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002091,
          "fieldName": "Frame"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002092,
          "fieldName": "H.P.",
          "value": "1-1/2"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002093,
          "fieldName": "Hertz",
          "value": "60"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002524,
          "fieldName": "Mounting Option",
          "value": "Square Flange"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002104,
          "fieldName": "Overload",
          "value": "Automatic"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002105,
          "fieldName": "Phase",
          "value": "Single"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002109,
          "fieldName": "RPM",
          "value": "3450"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002110,
          "fieldName": "Service Factor",
          "value": "1.1"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002112,
          "fieldName": "Speeds",
          "value": "Single"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002114,
          "fieldName": "Voltage",
          "value": "115/230"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002108,
          "fieldName": "Rotation",
          "value": "CCW Pump End"
        }
      ],
      "number": "USQ1152",
      "type": "item",
      "statusId": 4000004050
    },
    {
      "createDate": 1468872878845,
      "updateDate": 1495111010291,
      "deleted": 0,
      "allListsItemCount": 0,
      "assets": [
        {
          "createDate": 1469129652335,
          "updateDate": 1471625094427,
          "deleted": 0,
          "url": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg",
          "parentId": 10270309,
          "typeId": 4000014573,
          "filename": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg",
          "seqOrder": 1,
          "printActive": 1,
          "webActive": 1,
          "thumbnail": 1,
          "flag1": 1,
          "typeName": "Web Thumbnail Image",
          "typeGroupCode": "PRIM",
          "id": 4063212157,
          "transformationSource": false,
          "primaryAsset": false
        },
        {
          "createDate": 1469129652335,
          "updateDate": 1471625094427,
          "deleted": 0,
          "url": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif",
          "parentId": 10270309,
          "typeId": 4000014572,
          "filename": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif",
          "seqOrder": 2,
          "printActive": 1,
          "webActive": 0,
          "typeName": "Print Image",
          "typeGroupCode": "PRIM",
          "id": 4063212158,
          "transformationSource": false,
          "primaryAsset": false
        }
      ],
      "masterCategoryId": 4000593879,
      "listsCount": 0,
      "advTablesCount": 0,
      "id": 10270309,
      "values": [
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002078,
          "fieldName": "Amps",
          "value": "10.4"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20000921,
          "fieldKey": "Item_ID",
          "fieldName": "Item ID",
          "value": "USQ1202"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002075,
          "fieldKey": "Inv_Mast_UID",
          "fieldName": "Inv_Mast_UID",
          "value": "6737"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002141,
          "fieldKey": "Web_Description",
          "fieldName": "Web&UPC Description",
          "value": "CENTURY MOTOR                     NS"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002190,
          "fieldKey": "Web_Image",
          "fieldName": "Image Name LR",
          "value": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002191,
          "fieldName": "Image Name HR",
          "value": "A_O_Smith_SQ1032"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002089,
          "fieldName": "Features",
          "value": "Used on many Sta-Rite - Red Jacket, Pac Fab & American pprojets and Sears jet and pool pumps,High & low service factors, 303 Stainless steel threaded shaft, 50 Degrees C ambient, Capacitor sart"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002102,
          "fieldName": "Notes",
          "value": "199"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002088,
          "fieldName": "Enclosure",
          "value": "Open Drip Proof"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002091,
          "fieldName": "Frame"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002092,
          "fieldName": "H.P.",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002093,
          "fieldName": "Hertz",
          "value": "60"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002524,
          "fieldName": "Mounting Option",
          "value": "NEMA 56C Face"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002104,
          "fieldName": "Overload",
          "value": "Automatic"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002105,
          "fieldName": "Phase",
          "value": "Single"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002109,
          "fieldName": "RPM",
          "value": "3450"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002110,
          "fieldName": "Service Factor",
          "value": "1.1"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002112,
          "fieldName": "Speeds",
          "value": "Single"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002114,
          "fieldName": "Voltage",
          "value": "230"
        },
        {
          "languageId": 1,
          "fieldId": 20002108,
          "fieldName": "Rotation",
          "value": "CCWPE-Not Reversible"
        }
      ],
      "number": "USQ1202",
      "type": "item",
      "statusId": 4000004050
    }
]
```

}

This what I have started with:

```
string itemJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(itemJson);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is hacky but works:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string itemJson = @"{'items':[{'createDate':1468872878834,'updateDate':1498075185297,'deleted':0,'allListsItemCount':0,'assets':[{'createDate':1469129652323,'updateDate':1471625094427,'deleted':0,'url':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg','parentId':10270308,'typeId':4000014573,'filename':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg','seqOrder':1,'printActive':1,'webActive':1,'thumbnail':1,'flag1':1,'typeName':'Web Thumbnail Image','typeGroupCode':'PRIM','id':4063212155,'transformationSource':false,'primaryAsset':false},{'createDate':1469129652323,'updateDate':1471625094427,'deleted':0,'url':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif','parentId':10270308,'typeId':4000014572,'filename':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif','seqOrder':2,'printActive':1,'webActive':0,'typeName':'Print Image','typeGroupCode':'PRIM','id':4063212156,'transformationSource':false,'primaryAsset':false}],'masterCategoryId':4000593879,'listsCount':0,'advTablesCount':0,'id':10270308,'values':[{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002078,'fieldName':'Amps','value':'19.20/9.60'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20000921,'fieldKey':'Item_ID','fieldName':'Item ID','value':'USQ1152'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002075,'fieldKey':'Inv_Mast_UID','fieldName':'Inv_Mast_UID','value':'6736'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002081,'fieldName':'Bearings','value':'Sealed Ball'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002141,'fieldKey':'Web_Description','fieldName':'Web&UPC Description','value':'CENTURY MOTOR                     NS'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002190,'fieldKey':'Web_Image','fieldName':'Image Name LR','value':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002191,'fieldName':'Image Name HR','value':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002089,'fieldName':'Features','value':'Used on many Sta-Rite - Red Jacket, Pac Fab & American pprojets and Sears jet and pool pumps,High & low service factors, 303 Stainless steel threaded shaft, 50 Degrees C ambient, Capacitor sart'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002088,'fieldName':'Enclosure','value':'Open Drip Proof'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002091,'fieldName':'Frame'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002092,'fieldName':'H.P.','value':'1-1/2'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002093,'fieldName':'Hertz','value':'60'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002524,'fieldName':'Mounting Option','value':'Square Flange'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002104,'fieldName':'Overload','value':'Automatic'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002105,'fieldName':'Phase','value':'Single'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002109,'fieldName':'RPM','value':'3450'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002110,'fieldName':'Service Factor','value':'1.1'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002112,'fieldName':'Speeds','value':'Single'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002114,'fieldName':'Voltage','value':'115/230'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002108,'fieldName':'Rotation','value':'CCW Pump End'}],'number':'USQ1152','type':'item','statusId':4000004050},{'createDate':1468872878845,'updateDate':1495111010291,'deleted':0,'allListsItemCount':0,'assets':[{'createDate':1469129652335,'updateDate':1471625094427,'deleted':0,'url':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg','parentId':10270309,'typeId':4000014573,'filename':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg.jpg','seqOrder':1,'printActive':1,'webActive':1,'thumbnail':1,'flag1':1,'typeName':'Web Thumbnail Image','typeGroupCode':'PRIM','id':4063212157,'transformationSource':false,'primaryAsset':false},{'createDate':1469129652335,'updateDate':1471625094427,'deleted':0,'url':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif','parentId':10270309,'typeId':4000014572,'filename':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032.tif','seqOrder':2,'printActive':1,'webActive':0,'typeName':'Print Image','typeGroupCode':'PRIM','id':4063212158,'transformationSource':false,'primaryAsset':false}],'masterCategoryId':4000593879,'listsCount':0,'advTablesCount':0,'id':10270309,'values':[{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002078,'fieldName':'Amps','value':'10.4'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20000921,'fieldKey':'Item_ID','fieldName':'Item ID','value':'USQ1202'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002075,'fieldKey':'Inv_Mast_UID','fieldName':'Inv_Mast_UID','value':'6737'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002141,'fieldKey':'Web_Description','fieldName':'Web&UPC Description','value':'CENTURY MOTOR                     NS'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002190,'fieldKey':'Web_Image','fieldName':'Image Name LR','value':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032_lg'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002191,'fieldName':'Image Name HR','value':'A_O_Smith_SQ1032'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002089,'fieldName':'Features','value':'Used on many Sta-Rite - Red Jacket, Pac Fab & American pprojets and Sears jet and pool pumps,High & low service factors, 303 Stainless steel threaded shaft, 50 Degrees C ambient, Capacitor sart'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002102,'fieldName':'Notes','value':'199'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002088,'fieldName':'Enclosure','value':'Open Drip Proof'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002091,'fieldName':'Frame'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002092,'fieldName':'H.P.','value':'2'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002093,'fieldName':'Hertz','value':'60'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002524,'fieldName':'Mounting Option','value':'NEMA 56C Face'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002104,'fieldName':'Overload','value':'Automatic'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002105,'fieldName':'Phase','value':'Single'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002109,'fieldName':'RPM','value':'3450'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002110,'fieldName':'Service Factor','value':'1.1'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002112,'fieldName':'Speeds','value':'Single'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002114,'fieldName':'Voltage','value':'230'},{'languageId':1,'fieldId':20002108,'fieldName':'Rotation','value':'CCWPE-Not Reversible'}],'number':'USQ1202','type':'item','statusId':4000004050}]}";
        dynamic rss = JObject.Parse(itemJson);
        dynamic items = rss.items;
        foreach (dynamic item in items)
        {
            dynamic values = item.values;
            foreach (dynamic val in values)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(val);
                if (val.fieldName == "Item ID")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(val.value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. While the other solutions were also very good. This solution gave me insight on how exactly to work through complex nested JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.id);
    foreach (var val in item.values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", val.fieldName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go would be to use  http://json2csharp.com/  to generate classes from your json.

Once you have the classes, you can add them into your project and use JSON.net to deserialize the whole structure.  Once you've deserialized the json to c# POCO's like

```
var  yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'your c# wrapper class'>(<your json>);
```

you can use Linq to query the objects.