# Loop through a JSON object that has nested objects and check boolean values c#

Tags: c#, loops, asp.net-core, recursion

I have 2 JSON objects that are deserialized into a c# object

the JSON objects both look like this

```
{
"obj2": {
  "booleanVal": true,
  "data": "me",
  "foo": {
    "Key": "",
    "booleanVal": false,
    "dataValue": "foo"
  },
  "Ide": {
    "booleanVal": true,
    "foo2": {
        "booleanVal": false,
        "dataValue": "foo"
      }
   }
}
```

```
{
"obj1": {
  "booleanVal": true,
  "data": "me",
  "foo": {
    "Key": "",
    "booleanVal": false,
    "dataValue": "foo"
  },
  "Ide": {
    "booleanVal": true,
    "foo2": {
        "booleanVal": false,
        "dataValue": "foo"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to loop through the c# object obj1 check the booleanVal to compare it to the booleanval of obj2, I cant seem to figure out a good way to go through the object to the last nested object the reach the booleanVal, what i tried so far is something like this

```
private void loop(obj1, obj2)
{
  foreach (var p in obj1)
            {
                foreach (var c in obj2)
                {

                    if (p.booleanVal != c.booleanVal)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("illegal");
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: are you iterating through two lists?

Comment: Add more details about what you exactly need to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with C#: How do I iterate through a nested JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418156/working-with-c-how-do-i-iterate-through-a-nested-json-using-newtonsoft-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq.
Add below line at top of your .cs file.

```
using System.Linq;
```

There are many possible ways to easily iterate through list using linq. Below 2 examples will give you an idea about how to reach till last nested object and compare it. Maybe you need to modify it according to your need.

**Example 1: Match booleanVal separately at every level**

```
foreach (var obj1Item in obj1)
{
    if(obj2.Any(obj2Item => obj2Item.booleanVal == obj1Item.booleanVal))
    {
        // first level booleanVal matched
    }

    if(obj2.Any(obj2Item => obj2Item.foo.booleanVal == obj1Item.foo.booleanVal))
    {
        // second level booleanVal matched
    }

    if(obj2.Any(obj2Item => obj2Item.Ide.booleanVal == obj1Item.Ide.booleanVal))
    {
        // second level booleanVal matched
    }

    if(obj2.Any(obj2Item => obj2Item.Ide.foo2.booleanVal == obj1Item.Ide.foo2.booleanVal))
    {
        // third level booleanVal matched
    }

}
```

**Example 2: Match booleanVal at all levels at the same time**

```
foreach (var obj1Item in obj1)
{
    if(obj2.Any(obj2Item => obj2Item.booleanVal == obj1Item.booleanVal && 
                            obj2Item.foo.booleanVal == obj1Item.foo.booleanVal &&
                            obj2Item.Ide.booleanVal == obj1Item.Ide.booleanVal &&
                            obj2Item.Ide.foo2.booleanVal == obj1Item.Ide.foo2.booleanVal))
    {
        // booleanVal at all levels matched
    }
}
```